# Pip2PI uses Python 3 packages, even in a Python 2 virtualenv?

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, pip2pi

I am trying to use pip2tgz to build a pipPI compatible package for installation on a non-connected machine.  I am working from a python 2.7. virtual env and have verified that pip2tgz is running from it.  When I attempt to add, e.g., south the package, pip2tgz downloads the file South-0.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.  dir2pi does not index that file and, on the target machine, when I attempt to install south, I get the error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/www/pkgs/simple/south/'
```

Is it possible that pip2tgz is not respecting its python version, when it downloads packages?  Can I force it to stick to the tgz format?

Comment: This isn't an issue I've seen before. What package are you trying to download that I could use to try and recreate the issue with?

Comment: @DavidWolever As you can see, this is an issue from a while ago.  Also I am seriously pyn00b.  I don't recall the details (but can probably recover them, if it is useful)  It seems that there were two very different distribution mechanisms.  "South" used the newer (Python 3 compatible) mechanism and pipPI couldn't handle it.

Comment: Thanks! In that case, ya, it does look like the issue's been fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After upgrading pip2pi to version 0.6.2 ( python wheel fixes ), my local repository worked.

so try:

```
pip install --upgrade pip2pi
```

... and recreate you local repository.

Answer (score -1):

Try to locate the package on http://pypi.python.org and copy the link of the tgz file and run

```
pip2tgz PATH/TO/DIR URL/TO/TGZ
```

and remove the md5sum (everything behind the #).